# What should I refactor in my Python Class?

Tags: python, exception

I'm fairly new to Python. And this is my first class:

```
import config   # Ficheiro de configuracao
import twitter
import random
import sqlite3
import time
import bitly_api #https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python

class TwitterC:
    def logToDatabase(self, tweet, timestamp):
        # Will log to the database
        database      = sqlite3.connect('database.db') # Create a database file
        cursor        = database.cursor() # Create a cursor
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS twitter(id_tweet INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, tweet TEXT, timestamp TEXT);") # Make a table
        # Assign the values for the insert into
        msg_ins       = tweet
        timestamp_ins = timestamp
        values        = [msg_ins, timestamp_ins]
        # Insert data into the table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO twitter(tweet, timestamp) VALUES(?, ?)", values)
        database.commit() # Save our changes
        database.close() # Close the connection to the database

    def shortUrl(self, url):
        bit = bitly_api.Connection(config.bitly_username, config.bitly_key) # Instanciar a API
        return bit.shorten(url) # Encurtar o URL

    def updateTwitterStatus(self, update): 
        short   = self.shortUrl(update["url"]) # Vou encurtar o URL
        update  = update["msg"] + short['url']
        # Will post to twitter and print the posted text
        api     = twitter.Api(consumer_key=config.consumer_key, 
                                   consumer_secret=config.consumer_secret, 
                                   access_token_key=config.access_token_key, 
                                   access_token_secret=config.access_token_secret)
        status  = api.PostUpdate(update) # Fazer o update
        msg     = status.text # Vou gravar o texto enviado para a variavel 'msg'
        # Vou gravar p a Base de Dados
        self.logToDatabase(msg, time.time())
        print msg # So p mostrar o texto enviado. Comentar esta linha de futuro.

x = TwitterC()
x.updateTwitterStatus({"url": "http://xxxx.com/?cat=49", "msg": "Searching for some ....? "})
```

My question. What should I refactor in this ugly code(I think)?

For example. When I try do duplicate a Twitter Update I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anlopes\workspace\redes_sociais\src\twitterC.py", line 42, in <module>
    x.updateTwitterStatus({"url": "http://xxx.com/?cat=49", "msg": "Searching for some ...? "})
  File "C:\Users\anlopes\workspace\redes_sociais\src\twitterC.py", line 35, in updateTwitterStatus
    status  = api.PostUpdate(update) # Fazer o update
  File "C:\home_python\python_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 2549, in PostUpdate
    self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
  File "C:\home_python\python_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 3484, in _CheckForTwitterError
    raise TwitterError(data['error'])
twitter.TwitterError: Status is a duplicate.
```

How can I for example catch this error in Python?

Some clues needed.

Best Regards,

Comment: Is that your first class? Do some warming up with the language like a mortal being :D

Comment: What do you mean by "When I try do [to?] duplicate a Twitter Update." Are you doing something in addition to the code you've displayed? I don't see any attempt to duplicate anything in this code.

Comment: Should this be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well. When I send the same Update twice, the twitter package raise an exception. I wan't do send this as a warning to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to write a function that connects to and disconnects from the database and during the connection time does some stuff. It could look something like this:

```
class DBFactory(object):
    def DBConnection(self, Func, args):
        database      = sqlite3.connect('database.db') # Create a database file
        cursor        = database.cursor() # Create a cursor

        Func(cursor, args)

        database.commit() # Save our changes
        database.close() # Close the connection to the database
```

Now the `Func` and `args` parameter actually do the interaction to the database. For example something like this:

```
def CreateTable(cursor, args):
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0};".format(args)) # Make a table
```

Now if you wish to create a table you simple have to make this call:

```
f = DBFactory()
f.DBConnection(CreateTable, "twitter(id_tweet INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, tweet TEXT, timestamp TEXT)"
```

You can proceed similarly with other interactions to the database for example inserting or deleting entries. Each time calling the `DBConnection` method. This should modularize your class a little better. At least in my opinion.

Please note that I did not give this code above a try, so there might be a typo in there, but I hope you get the idea. I hope this helped ya

Cherio
Woltan

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Great tip about the database. I will try to put it in practice. Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

As the output states clearly, your code is raising a twitter.TwitterError exception. You catch it like this:

```
try:
    # yadda yadda
except twitter.TwitterError:
    # exception code
else:
    # happy flow code, optionally.
finally:
    # must-run code, optionally
```

Now, **when you are writing your first class and don't know how to catch exceptions in a language, you don't try to fetch twitter updates and save them in a database. You print "Hello World!"**. Go do a tutorial :D.

Comment: Why are you assuming André doesn't know how to catch exceptions in Python? @André, do you?

Comment: Well... his question is "How can I catch this error in Python?". Unless it meant avoiding the error or something,... or it was rhetorical :P

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I don't haven't a clue on how exception in Python works. I will read some documentation about.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to refactor is to get this code out of a class. It has absolutely no need to be in one. This should be a module, with standalone functions.

**Edit to add more explanation** In Python, most code is grouped naturally into modules. Classes are mainly useful for when you will need discrete instances, each with their own data. This is not the case here - you are just using the class as a placeholder for related code. That's what modules are for.

If, for example, you wanted to model an individual Tweet, which knew about its own content and how to save itself into a database, that would indeed be a good use of OOP. But "stuff that's related to Twitter" is not a class, it's a module.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why you think this. I'm not necessarily disagreeing with you, but I'd like to hear more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have write this in a class because I wanted to test some OOP with Python. But I will add to this code the functionalities to post to Facebook, MySpace, Orkut and some more Social Networks. Should I handle this without OOP? Best Regards,